# multiple components in one template

Tags: angular, components, angular2-template, angular-components

I have main component, whose template is another component. I was wondering can I have 2 components in one template, both to be displayed. For example, I've created component which contains navigation, and the other one contains body. Since I need navigation to stay the same in all other pages, I made a component for it. How can I solve this? Is it even possible?

e.g

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<firstComponent></firstComponent>
<secondComponent></secondComponent>
`
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by having them as two separate components and adding it to declarations array of the respective module

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'firstComponent',
template: `
         ..................
`
})
export class FirstComponent {

}

Second component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'secondComponent',
template: `
         ..................
`
})
export class SecondComponent {

}


export class AppModule {

declarations:[AppComponent,FirstComponent,SecondComponent]
```

Comment: I've already added all my components to the declaration array in the AppModule, having them as two seperate components. Now I don't know how can I combine them as template in my AppComponent, so that both are displayed at the same time.

Comment: your previous AppComponent's template will put both of these components into one view as expected